# Autocmd seems to not trigger cinkeys

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my vimrc

```
" Python indenting and folding
au! FileType python set foldmethod=indent
au! FileType python set nosmartindent

" C++ indenting and folding
au! FileType cpp set cino=i-s
au! FileType cpp set cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
au! FileType cpp set cinkeys-=0#
au! FileType cpp set smartindent
au! FileType cpp set foldmethod=syntax

fu! FUNC_ECHOVAR(varname)
  :let varstr=a:varname
  :exec 'let g:foo = &'.varstr
  :echo varstr.' = '.g:foo
endfu
command! -nargs=1 ECHOVAR :call FUNC_ECHOVAR(<f-args>)


func! MYINFO()
    :ECHOVAR cino
    :ECHOVAR cinkeys
    :ECHOVAR foldmethod
    :ECHOVAR filetype
    :ECHOVAR smartindent
endfu
command! MYINFOCMD call MYINFO() <C-R>
```

when I open a C++ file and execute the MYINFOCMD command I see this printout

```
cino = {1s
cinkeys = 0{0,},),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
foldmethod = syntax
filetype = cpp
smartindent = 0
```

I don't understand why the autocmd FileType cpp has failed to set these variables correctly, or at least the way I expected them to be set.

Does anyone know why my au! commands are not triggering when I load a .cpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:au!` at most once for each autocommand event and pattern, since it removes previously defined autocommands.  (Use it in case your vimrc file gets `source`d more than once, so the autocommands are not duplicated.)  From `:help autocmd-remove`:

```
:au[tocmd]! [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
            Remove all autocommands associated with {event} and
            {pat}, and add the command {cmd}.  See
            |autocmd-nested| for [nested].
```

Alternatively, put all your autocommands in a group and use `:au!` just once (`:help autocmd-groups`):

```
augroup Erotemic
  au!
  " Python indenting and folding
  au FileType python set foldmethod=indent
  au FileType python set nosmartindent

  " C++ indenting and folding
  au FileType cpp set cino=i-s
  au FileType cpp set cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
  au FileType cpp set cinkeys-=0#
  au FileType cpp set smartindent
  au FileType cpp set foldmethod=syntax
augroup END
```

Here is what happens when I try the first two of your autocommand lines, and then list the `FileType python` autocommands after each one:

```
:au! FileType python set foldmethod=indent
:au FileType python

--- Auto-Commands ---
FileType
    python    set foldmethod=indent

:au! FileType python set nosmartindent
:au FileType python

--- Auto-Commands ---
FileType
    python    set nosmartindent
```

Comment: That makes sense, I thought ! just meant force the operation. I was having trouble so I just thought, I'll force everything. I just :%s/^au!/au/ and my troubles went away. Thank you!